# How to store picture in picture library month and year wise

Tags: document-library, picture-library

In SharePoint 2013 need suggestion to stores picture/images month and years wise so it will be easy to refer in future.

Is there any other way instead of creating folders and store in Picture library OR this is the right way.

Please advice if something new provided by SharePoint 2013 to archive above task instead of creating monthly folders in picture library and storing the images.

Comment: You could tag the the pictures with month and year metadata and then filter by those.

Comment: Can you please provide the step or link.

Comment: General about Managed Metadata: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-managed-metadata-a180fa28-6405-4679-9ec3-81d2028c4efc

Comment: Thanks for the provided link. I don't have rights for MMS. Can you please suggest some other option

Comment: Well, you could just create 2 additional choice columns to the picture library with the 12 months, and some years values and set them to required, and use filtering on the year and months afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But one doubt I've storing all pictures/images in one document library it will not give any performance/slowness while filtering or sorting the data. Please advice

Answer (score 0):

The folder solution would be recommended ONLY if the permission on these images are going to be very granular. Normally libraries that contain documents such as Policy & Procedures would use folder potentially but in your case I would say you wouldn't.

With that said the solution of creating 2 choice columns for "Year" and "Month" is going to be a great solution. Once all your documents are tagged with a year and month you can then "group" the documents by year and month to ensure your users can navigate through the images similar to a folder structure :) As for performance concerns, your image library should not slow down if your view item limit isn't greater than 50 per page. If so you may have a separate issue in performance needs.

Recap - Steps to your solution:

1. Create 2 Choice Columns (Year, Month)
2. Apply the correct metadata to all content
3. (Optional) Group the files to ensure user can easily navigate images
4. Ensure your item limit is >= 50

[image]